# iOS - Parent VC Auto Layout breaks after dismissing modal presented by child VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, orientation, modalviewcontroller

I have a slightly complex structure (app is iPad only):

My root VC, MainVC, is a custom container view controller with a logo on the top right (constrained with Auto Layout).
Below the logo there is a fullscreen container view which embeds a Navigation Controller subclass, call it NavVC. This allows the logo to be fixed and always visible while NavVC pushes new controllers.

NavVC has a root VC called MenuVC.

MenuVC pushes DataVC using custom transition.

DataVC presents ModalVC (which is Apple's QLPreviewController) modally.

I need the whole app to be Landscape only, except from the ModalVC which needs to be Portrait only (I guess it could be both but it's displaying a portrait PDF so it doesn't make much sense to have it landscape)

What I have done is:

I enabled all rotations in the project settings.

I added this code to MainVC:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

This locks all the app in Landscape only but for some reason ModalVC is still able to rotate to all orientations, which would be ideal, but unfortunately this causes my problem:

If I rotate the iPad to Portrait while ModalVC is presented (which is what users will do to read the PDF) and then dismiss ModalVC while still in Portrait, the logo which is MainVC shifts 256 points to the left, breaking the constraints (although Xcode gives no errors).
Interestingly 256 is the difference between the width and the height of the iPad... coincidence?

Not sure if useful but when presenting ModalVC I get this warning in Xcode:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for QLRemotePreviewContentController

Comment: It seems to be a bug in QLPreviewController... Swapping it for a UIViewController doesn't produce the same results and works fine.